# Как правильно оформить название "Ванька-золотые руки"?

Tags: дефис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужен ли здесь дефис?

> Ванька-золотые руки

И как правильно склонять это выражение?

> У Ваньки-золотые руки вырос такой же сын.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Действительно, мы пишем ***мастер золотые руки***.

Грамота.ру Вопрос № 226034
Как правильно пишется выражение "мастер золотые руки"?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Верно: мастер золотые руки.

Тогда: **Ванька золотые руки.**

2) Склоняется только первая часть: **у Ваньки золотые руки.**

Сравнить: Владимира Красное Солнышко (прозвище не склоняется). Но: Соньку Золотую ручку.

Comment: Не бывает дефисов между словом и словосочетанием. Может быть разве что тире с пробелами. Но и это в данном случае вряд ли.

Comment: Решила на всякий случай убрать и дефис, и тире.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: Ванька золотые руки. По аналогии мастер золотые руки, мастер на все руки, медведь липовая нога.